# C++: Why my hash_map is giving me an ordered result like a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable, binary-search-tree

Since map is implemented using a tree and hash_map using a hash, I created a code to test if my map would give me an ordered result and the hash_map would print my examples in the order that they were registered

```
map<string, int> mymap;
hash_map<string, int> myhashmap;

mymap["lucas"] = 1;
mymap["abel"] = 2;
mymap["jose"] = 1;

myhashmap["lucas"] = 1;
myhashmap["abel"] = 2;
myhashmap["jose"] = 1;

for(map<string, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++){
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}

cout << endl;

for(hash_map<string, int>::iterator it = myhashmap.begin(); it != myhashmap.end(); it++){
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
```

but both results were:

```
abel 2
jose 1
lucas 1
```

why the hash_map gave me an ordered result?

Comment: That's a pure coincidence. Add more strings to see it eventually getting out of order.

Comment: I rolled a six-sided die twice, and it came up 1 and 2. Shouldn't it be more random?

Comment: How do you know that it's ordered by name and not by hash?

Comment: I tested now using 6 keys for both map and hash_map, and the result wasen't ordered anymore. Maybe just coincidence at the first time...  mymap["lucas"] = 1; mymap["abel"] = 2;  mymap["jose"] = 1; mymap["john"] = 5; mymap["andrew"] = 23; mymap["xen"] = 12;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no order guarantee in hash_map - which means it can store results in **any** order, depending on implementation.